Is Induction implied within Definition of Recursion?
Hi I was reading about definition of Addition:
n + 0 = n
n + S(m) = S(n + m)
Between these two above mentioned steps, moving from + 0 to + S(m). How can we be SURE that this is a valid extrapolation. How does it validly encompass "applies to any m" because something like that is usually proven through induction. I think "extrapolation is true inductively" is implicitly assumed here when moving from 0 to m. S is the Successor Function.
Am I asking this question right?!

$S(m)$, is that the successor function?

@Dominique Yes S is Successor Function...

Correct. The induction axiom is used to show that addition is uniquely and well defined by these two formulas and to check the desired properties.

You might enjoy playing https://adam.math.hhu.de/#/g/leanprover-community/nng4 which formally builds a lot of arithmetic in Lean 4 (a formal theorem prover) in a game-like setting.  You will see the explicit use of induction in defining addition and proving many basic properties (like commutativity).

I'm not sure this answers your question, but using a form of natural deduction and set theory, and starting from Peano's Axioms, we can formally construct, i.e. prove the existence of a unique binary function ($+$) on $N$ with the properties you list here. The long and convoluted  proof requires several applications of the induction axiom.

Note to readers: The OP is currently exploring the Peano axioms, if that wasn't obvious (note prior questions).

@StevenGubkin Thanks I will look into it.

@DanChristensen I thought it would be a simple thing to understand. I ideally would have liked to know but maybe later. Thanks for your comment.

@DanChristensen When you said "convuluted proof" did you mean Inductively Prove for Base Case of n (n=0) and within that Inductively prove base + inductive step for m and then do the same for Inductive Step of n = n + 1?
Because that's what I realised it'll take to prove this. I am trying...

@AshishShukla I mean only that it is a long and complicated proof that requires several proofs by induction to construct the addition function on N and prove that it uniquely satisfies that the properties you list above.

@fedja You are saying is that there is a proof for these two or addition as a whole?! But Daniel R Collins in the comments in his answer says that there IS NO PROOF, it is a definition, you just accept it. Maybe I am not understanding your comment correctly.

I'm saying that there is a proof of the related statement accompanying every such definition beyond the axiom set, which is "There exists unique $+:N\times N\to N$ such that..." and that this proof relies heavily on the axiom of induction.

@DanChristensen I agree that the proof I posted in my answer would be considered "long and convoluted" by modern students and that $2$ counts as "several", but, as I said in the post, you might have intimidated the OP a bit beyond reasonable with your comment, so I decided to clarify the matters a bit :lol:

@fedja See my comment on your answer.

See my comment to fedja


Between these two above mentioned steps, moving from + 0 to + S(m).
How can we be SURE that this is a valid extrapolation. How does it
validly encompass "applies to any m" because something like that is
usually proven through induction.


It's not an extrapolation.
It's two separate parts of a definition.
It applies to any natural number by definition.

If you know about recursion, then it's important to note that $n + 0 = n$ is the base case, and $n + S(m) = S(n + m)$ is the recursive step. You need both of these pieces for a complete definition, and you cannot "prove" one from the other.
A separate question is whether the function described by these equations is well-defined, that is, actually exists and is unique. A proof of this fact can be seen under Proposition 1.2 in this paper.

So "by definition" is like Axiom?! You just accept it? You know this part is confusing, I feel as if Addition is being defined in terms of addition like m+0=m. We are already using "+" in definition. Sometimes I feel Successor Function is defined in terms of addition (S(n) = n+1) but it's written that addition is defined in terms of Successor Function. I am still working on it though. Thanks...

@AshishShukla: Yes. Note the defining right-hand side $m$ has no "+", and so avoids a circular definition. The examples at Wikipedia may clarify.

Hi Daniel,
So I have come up with a proof why m + S(n) = S(m+n). Is it valid?! So:
To prove: m + S(n) = S(m+n)

Hi Daniel,
So I have come up with a proof why m + S(n) = S(m+n) is valid?! So:
To prove: m + S(n) = S(m+n)
Previously known Fact: m+0 = m --- EQ1
Inductive Proof for some variable k, Base Case: k=0
m + S(0) = S(m+0)
Therefore: m + S(0) = S(m) using EQ1 above
Inductive Hypothesis(k=k): m +S(k) = S(m + k) --- EQ2
Inductive Step(k=S(k)):
m + S(S(k)) = S(m + S(k))
m + S(S(k)) = S(S(m+k)) --- Using EQ2
Therefore it proves that it is ok to say, m + S(n) = S(m+n)
Is this proof correct?! Even if it is correct I am not sure how it defines addition but I am learning...

@AshishShukla: No. It is a definition; you can't prove it.

@DanielRCollins if you look at the comments on my question above you'll see that Dan Christensen says there IS A proof and it's a convoluted one with Induction, that's where I got the idea of proving it...

@AshishShukla: No. DC said one can, "prove the existence of a unique binary function (+) on N with the properties you list here", which is a different fact. See Proposition 1.2 in this paper.

Oh, ok. But if I tell you that I feel there is something missing, is it OK to explore or will that be a waste of time, I should simply accept m+S(n)=S(m+n) as fact and proceed further?

@AshishShukla: Extended discussion in comments is ill-advised, and may get deleted at any time. You may possibly have better luck asking a question on SE Mathematics (note that's different from this site SE Mathematics Educators).

No. It is a definition; you can't prove it See my last comment in the OP :-)

@fedja Re: "... you can't prove it" Starting from only Peano's Axioms and the axioms of set theory, you actually construct a subset of $N^3$ using the Subset Axiom and prove that it is the required function (several hundred lines of formal proof). Then you can formally prove that it is uniquely determined.

...That subset: $\forall a, b, c : [(a,b,c)\in add \iff (a,b,c)\in N^3 \land \forall d\subset N^3 : [\forall e\in N:(e,0,e) \in d \land \forall e,f,g\in N: [(e,f,g) \in d \implies (e,S(f), S(g)) \in d]] \implies (a,b,c)\in d]$

... The formal proof (719 lines): https://dcproof.com/AdditionOnN.htm

... The formal proof of uniqueness (84 lines): https://dcproof.com/AdditionOnNUnique.htm

For obvious reasons, most authors skip even any mention of the existence proof and start with a "definition."

@DanChristensen Correct. All depends on how exactly "formal" one wants to be. See the beginning paragraph in my post. I drew the line at "human verifiability". If you think that something in my posted proof is not rigorous enough from this standpoint, feel free to comment!

@fedja The OP was wondering : "Should I simply accept m+S(n)=S(m+n) as fact and proceed further?" Given limitations of time and motivation, it is usually simply stated as a "definition." As it turns out, there is no harm in this approach, but anyone like the OP here who is interested in foundational issues, should know that it can be proven as a theorem from Peano's Axioms and the axioms of set theory.

@DanChristensen Absolutely correct again. My (relatively mild) objection was not to "it can be proven" but to "long and convoluted" only (the two words that might scare the OP away from the attempt to find or understand the proof).

@fedja My relatively mild objection was only to your claim that, "It is a definition; you can't prove it." An instructor might legitimately say that a formal proof is "beyond the scope of the course."

@DanChristensen your claim that, "It is a definition; you can't prove it." Are you sure you are not confusing me and Daniel? :-) My comment started with these words as a quote

I thought that it would make sense to post the proof of existence and uniqueness of addition (Dan might intimidate the OP a bit beyond reasonable by saying that it is "long and convoluted"). This proof might not pass the standards of Leanprover, but pretty much every human mathematician will be satisfied with it.
Fix $n\in\mathbb N$. We will show that there exists unique $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ such that
$$
f(0)=n;
\\
\forall x\in\mathbb N, f(S(x))=S(f(x))\,.
$$
Uniqueness: Let $f_1, f_2$ be two such functions. Consider the set $A=\{x\in\mathbb N: f_1(x)=f_2(x)\}$. Then
$$
f_1(0)=n=f_2(0)\,,
$$
so $0\in A$.
Also, if $x\in A$, then
$$
f_1(S(x))=S(f_1(x))=S(f_2(x))=f_2(S(x))\,,
$$
so $S(x)\in A$. Thus (by the induction axiom) $A=\mathbb N$, i.e., $f_1\equiv f_2$.
Existence:
Call $U\subset \mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ good if
\begin{align}
1)&\ (0,n)\in U;
\\
2)&\ (a,b)\in U\Longrightarrow (S(a),S(b))\in U.
\end{align}
Good sets exist (for instance, $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ is good. Also the intersection of any set of good sets is good. Thus we can define $F=\cap_{U\text{ good}}U$, which is the minimal good set.
I claim that $F$ is a graph of a function $f$ with the required properties. The only interesting part to prove here is that it is a graph, i.e., for every $x\in \mathbb N$, the cross-section $F\cap(\{x\}\times \mathbb N)$ has exactly one element.
Let $A$ be the set of $x\in \mathbb N$ with that property. $(0,n)\in F$. If there is $(0,m)\in F$ with $m\ne n$, we can safely remove it from $F$ and get a smaller good set (the only issue that may arise is with (2), but $0$ is nobody's successor, so it won't), which contradicts the minimality of $F$. Thus the cross-section of $F$ at $0$ is $\{n\}$ and $0\in A$.
Let $x\in A$. Then there is unique $y\in \mathbb N$ with $(x,y)\in F$. Hence $(S(x),S(y))\in F$. Again, if $(S(x),z)\in F$ for some $z\ne S(y)$, then we can remove it. The only issue that may arise with such removal is that we might have $z=S(w)$ with $(t,w)\in F$ and $S(t)=S(x)$. But the latter equality would imply $t=x$ (Peano!) and thus $w=y$ and $S(w)=S(y)\ne z$. So we conclude that the cross-section of $F$ at $S(x)$ is $\{S(y)\}$, i.e., $S(x)\in A$, and one more application of the induction axiom finishes the story.
That is how "long and convoluted" it all is. If you look at the proof attentively, you'll realize that there is nothing special about addition in it. And, indeed, you can run the same proof for every recursive definition with usual or even transfinite induction. Or you can do even better by formalizing the very notion of "recursive definition" and proving the corresponding (meta-)theorem, which is what Daniel was hinting at.
I hope this clarifies things a bit for you, but feel free to ask additional questions if some extra explanations are needed.
